# @url.action() doesnt work when passed as a string

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is there any problem with the below code..??

```
menu += '<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="@Url.Action("HomeModules","Home")">';

$("#identifier").append(menu)
```

It doesnt work and throws an error like below

No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:5001/Home/@Url.Action(

Please help

Comment: `append()` and `page not found` doesn't seem connected.

Comment: @fedesc the question is if 
menu += '<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="@Url.Action("HomeModules","Home")">';
is correct???

Comment: no cuase it's just a string and thats not a valid url string. Try something like this.

>>> `menu += '<a class="dropdown-toggle" href=" + @Url.Action("HomeModules","Home") + ">'`  but i'm not sure about what is @URL.action just that it looks like a helper function which then, shouldn't be a string

Comment: it throws an error like this   No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:5001/Home/$%7B@Url.Action(

Comment: I've changed the code line to use `+` instead of [template literals```](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) because the comment herre changes it. The new edit doesn't work? without template literals? this? : `menu += '<a class="dropdown-toggle" href=" + @Url.Action("HomeModules","Home") + ">'`

Comment: no again it doesnt work.. used the same code u gave.. still no luck..